# Duplicate AD domain (users & groups)

Tags: active-directory

Imagine our AD domain is currently called DOMAIN1 but we want it to be called DOMAIN2. I know that we can't rename the domain because we've got Exchange servers in there so basically we're looking at a relatively major migration project. Parking servers & computers for now but we've got a reasonable number of users accounts and groups in DOMAIN1 and we'd like the exactly same in DOMAIN2.

So for example, my user account is domain1\rob.nicholson in the "IT Support" OU and I'm a member of domain1\group1 and domain1\group2. So OU "domain2\IT Support" needs creating (with same metadata), domain2\rob.nicholson needs creating (copying metadata again), domain2\group2 created, me added to it etc etc.

I'm looking for a tool that will, in effect, duplicate the AD structure in domain1 in domain2 for some objects, but not all (e.g. don't bother with computers).

Do such tools exist or am I barking up completely the wrong tree? No problem with considering commercial tools.

Suggestions for a good search term for this process appreciated as well.

Comment: I would ask the following: Is this change strictly "cosmetic" or are there real business, political, financial or functional reasons for the change?

Comment: +1 for joeqwerty's comment - migrating domains is generally a painful process wrought with many pitfalls and should only be done if there are real, justifiable reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try AD Migration Tool, which allows to migrate users, groups, and computers between AD DS domains in different forests (inter-forest migration) or between AD DS domains in the same forest (intra-forest migration)

[Active Directory Migration Tool version 3.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17918)

ADMT actually doesn't allow to migrate OU structure, for that purpose you can use LDIFDE tool.
Below is a link to the article which describes the process in details

[How to migrate OU structure from one domain to another](http://kpytko.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/how-to-migrate-ou-structure-from-one-domain-to-another/)

Answer (score 2):

Like at your case I would say at Microsoft Active directory while migrating the cloud migration,forest migration duplicity occur .This is not a very major issues but seems when occur creates and headache.

If you are in a need for a third party tool I would recommended you to use Lepide Active Directory management and reporting as I have use this tool before.

It’s able to migrate the whole forest without any duplicity and moreover it helps in other Active Directory management process also. It helps in maximizing the reach of user to the other forest enviorment. Try this tool out. Download its free version from the websites.

Answer (score 0):

As inhabitant mentioned, ADMT is the Microsoft provided tool to do domain migration. It works but does have minor issues that seem to be magnified in larger domain migrations. If you have a large-ish domain that you are trying to migrate all the objects over, you may want to consider some 3rd party migration tools.

I've used [Quest's Migration Manager](http://www.quest.com/migration-manager-for-active-directory/) and it is wonderful compared to a straight ADMT migration. Although, it is probably the most costly solution out there.

There are other solutions out there that will help you do migrations easier than a pure ADMT migration ([ADUM](http://www.managered.com/adum.html), [Immanus](http://realmsoft.co.uk/Pages/ADMigration)) that might be cheaper, but I've never used them and can't vouch for them personally.

Comment: What problems are you referring to? About a year and a half ago, I migrated about 20,000 objects between two forests over the course of a single weekend using ADMT without and problem.

Comment: Had some profile issues with migrated user/computer accounts and sid-history. Also had file permission issues on a file server we migrated - this was mainly due to it being used by OSX users who had painfully long file names and directory path names and, admittedly, may not have been fully ADMT's fault. :)

Comment: Ah, see I didn't migrate SID history so I didn't have to worry about that, and OS X's SMB implementation is certainly painful :)

Comment: ugh.. don't get me started on OSX and SMB..